# warning and error messages upon clicking QPYPI CLIENT

Tags: python, pip, kivy, qpython

I am new to coding with qpython. I am facing warning and error messages upon clicking QPYPI CLIENT. What could be the issue

```
ntry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x12458
WARNING: linker: libpython2.7.so.1.0: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x2
WARNING: linker: bz2.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x15b8
WARNING: linker: bz2.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff ar
```